# Macro wrting for Google E-Tablo (SpreadSheets)

Tags: google-apps-script

For google e-tablo.

This makes the filter active:

```js
spreadsheet.getRange('A1:AP3991').createFilter();
```

This makes the filter passive:

```js
spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().remove();
```

I would like to inquire whether the filter icon in the menu is active or inactive. What kind of formula should I write for this?

Comment: Are you looking for formulas or scripts here? You've provided code but asked for formulas...

Answer (score 0):

You can verify either you have an active filter in your spreadsheet with

`Logger.log(SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet().getFilter());`

If you have a filter (or several), the result will be `Filter`, otherwise, the output will be `null`